# PHP pass variables from form to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I'm more of a front-end developer, so the back-end stuff sometimes stumps me.

I have copied over some code from an existing website but it’s not functioning as expected on the new website.

I'm working with a hotel booking widget. There is a form on the homepage for inputting check in and check out dates. When the submit button is clicked, the form links to an availability table of all the room available.

On the current website, the dates inputted on the form are passed through to the availability table. However, when I copied the code over, it no longer functions as that. What am I missing?

Here is the form code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.MyDate1').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
    });

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.MyDate2').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
 minDate:  0,
onSelect: function(date){
var date2 = $('.MyDate2').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
            $('.MyDate1').datepicker('setDate', date2);
    });

</script>

<?php 
// ==================================================
// Displays the Booking Panel Date selection options.
// ==================================================

// Set up some default Check-in/Check-out Dates.
$checkinToday = date('d/m/Y');
$checkoutTomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+1, date('Y'));
$checkoutTomorrow = date('d/m/Y', $checkoutTomorrow);
?>
              <form name="bookingform" action="https://www.clarionsuitesgateway.com.au/clarionhotel/booking-system/" method="post">
              <div class="booking-h3">Check Availability</div>
              <div class="booking-row">
                <div class="booking-label">Check In Date</div>
                <div class="booking-field"><input name="frmCheckin" id="frmCheckin" type="text" class="MyDate1" value="<?php echo $checkinToday; ?>" style="width:100%" /></div>
              </div>
              <div class="booking-row">
                <div class="booking-label">Check Out Date</div>
                <div class="booking-field"><input name="frmCheckout" id="frmCheckout" type="text" class="MyDate2" value="<?php echo $checkoutTomorrow; ?>" style="width:100%" /></div>
              </div>
              <div class="booking-row">
                <div class="booking-row-box">
                  <div class="booking-label">Adults</div>
                  <div class="booking-field">
                      <select id="frmAdults" name="frmAdults">
                        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++): ?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                      </select>            
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="booking-row-box">
                  <div class="booking-label">Children</div>
                  <div class="booking-field">
                      <select id="frmChildren" name="frmChildren">
                        <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++): ?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                      </select>            
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br clear="all">
              </div>
              <div class="booking-row">
                <div class="booking-button">
                  <input type="submit" value="Check Availability" name="Send" alt="Check Availability" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="Submit" />
                </div>
              </div>              
              </form>
```

Here is the availability table it directs to:

```
<?php
// ==================================================
// BOOKING BUTTON specific page.
// ==================================================
// Set some default dates incase nothing is selected (we're not doing any error checking for this).
// Today
$CheckinDay = date('d');
$CheckinMonth = date('m');
$CheckinYear = date('Y');
// Tomorrow
$CurrentDate = date('Y/m/d');
$Tomorrow = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($CurrentDate)) ;
$Tomorrow = date('d/m/Y', $Tomorrow);
$arrCheckoutDate = explode("/", $Tomorrow);
$CheckoutDay = $arrCheckoutDate[0];
$CheckoutMonth = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $arrCheckoutDate[1], 1, 2012));
$CheckoutYear = $arrCheckoutDate[2];

$NumberAdults = 1;
$NumberChildren = 0;

if ( isset($_POST["Submit"]) ) 
{
    if ( strlen($_POST['frmCheckin']) )
    {
        $arrCheckinDate = explode("/", $_POST['frmCheckin']);
        $CheckinDay = $arrCheckinDate[0];
        $CheckinMonth = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $arrCheckinDate[1], 1, 2012));
        $CheckinYear = $arrCheckinDate[2];
    }
    if ( strlen($_POST['frmCheckout']) )
    {
        $arrCheckoutDate = explode("/", $_POST['frmCheckout']);
        $CheckoutDay = $arrCheckoutDate[0];
        $CheckoutMonth = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $arrCheckoutDate[1], 1, 2012));
        $CheckoutYear = $arrCheckoutDate[2];
    }
    $NumberAdults = $_POST['frmAdults'];
    $NumberChildren = $_POST['frmChildren'];
}
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="ContentOuterContainer">
  <div id="ContentInnerContainerBookings">
       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                 <iframe src="https://www.thebookingbutton.com.au/xxx/properties/xxx?utf8=%E2%9C%93&locale=en&check_in_date=<?php echo $CheckinDay;?>+<?php echo $CheckinMonth;?>+<?php echo $CheckinYear;?>&check_out_date=<?php echo $CheckoutDay;?>+<?php echo $CheckoutMonth;?>+<?php echo $CheckoutYear;?>&number_adults=<?php echo $NumberAdults; ?>&number_children=<?php echo $NumberChildren; ?>&commit=Check+Availability" height="590" width="1047" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>


       <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When I direct the form to the existing availability table, the dates are passed through. But when I copy the availability table to the new website, it stops passing through the dates. Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: So if you `print_r($_POST);` on the availability table page, is it empty?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please point me to a newbie's guide to executing that command?

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the fields on the 'new' site's table. Check to make sure they are the proper data type. Are you using MySQL? My guess is that you may not be connecting to the database properly. If it's working on your local server but it won't put any data into the new server table there is probably nothing wrong with the PHP or Javascript. Look into your database.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. Both sites are on the same server, which makes me think that if it's working on one, it should work on the other, correct? So when I set the form action to the existing availability table, the dates are passed through. But as soon as I set it to the new site, they aren't passed through.

Truly appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, it depends. I'll need a little more information from you. Are you using MySQL to store the data from the tables? Is it the exact same table you're trying to store the variables in? If it's a different table or a different database please let me know. Are you getting any error messages? On your SQL query try doing or die() to see if there is an error message.

Comment: If you're using the same script and the same table it should be working, but if you are changing to a different database it might not be going through on your settings.

Comment: Thanks again. The availability table itself is embedded with an iFrame, so it's coming from the server of the external booking app. I thought that the code on the page before the iFrame is the thing that is passing the dates through to the availability table - see next comment for the code I mean. I'm not getting error messages.

Comment: Specifically this part of the code:

`if ( isset($_POST["Submit"]) ) 
{
    if ( strlen($_POST['frmCheckin']) )
    {
        $arrCheckinDate = explode("/", $_POST['frmCheckin']);
        $CheckinDay = $arrCheckinDate[0];
        $CheckinMonth = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $arrCheckinDate[1], 1, 2012));
        $CheckinYear = $arrCheckinDate[2];
    }`

Comment: Cont'd:
`if ( strlen($_POST['frmCheckout']) )
    {
        $arrCheckoutDate = explode("/", $_POST['frmCheckout']);
        $CheckoutDay = $arrCheckoutDate[0];
        $CheckoutMonth = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $arrCheckoutDate[1], 1, 2012));
        $CheckoutYear = $arrCheckoutDate[2];
    }
    $NumberAdults = $_POST['frmAdults'];
    $NumberChildren = $_POST['frmChildren'];
}`